# Android feature toggle on UI - searching for design pattern

Tags: android, design-patterns, firebase-remote-config

I am searching for a design pattern i can use so i can feature toggle UI elements.

I have a simple screen that has a horizonal list at the bottom and at the top  is a photo.  clicking the list updates the photo. Anyway, thats not 
the issue.  This screen and code already exist. I have  a task to change what the list items look like. 
 I have a task to create a toggle such that the business can test this feature out, if they dont like it they want to revert back to the old design
 by simply using a feature toggle.

I dont want to copy all the files and make duplicates with a if else condition on the files if i can avoid it, (if you think its the better way let me know)
 i was thinking there is a design pattern something like a strategy pattern i could use to do this more cleanly.  even chain of responsilbity could be used. 
 but anyway, im not sure the best way to do this, how have you all handled feature toggles on UI elements ?

Comment: Strategy pattern. If it's only the UI that's updating and you're using MVP/MVVM then it's even more straightforward. All that changes is the inflated layout.

Comment: hats true, i could be over thinking it. i might do a proxy design pattern. toggle router is too much work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a toggle router, like here.

https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html